# Unable to import shape file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, shapefile, qgis

I can easily import data from qgis into Postgres.

But I need to use MySQL database now, while importing shape file I'm getting a missing column error - see the screenshot.

[image: Unable to load data in the shapefile]

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Avoid linking images, you should add all the necessary information in text.

Answer (score 0):

Install GDAL

Enter the code in terminal -->

```
ogr2ogr -f "MySQL"
MYSQL:"database_name,host=localhost,user=enter_username,password=enter_password,port=5432" -nln "name_of_the_file" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" QGIS_DATA/Data/NewLayers/school.shp-#filepath#
```